# Keeping the address space the same in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to keep my address the same, since I have a `JList` pointing towards `listAccts`. How do I make `ListAccts` have the same address space? Basically, how do I copy this object?

```
public class BankEngine extends AbstractListModel {

/** holds the accounts inside the bank engine */
private ArrayList<Account> listAccts;
/** holds all the actions the user has done. */
private ArrayList<Action> actions;
/** holds old versions of the bank. */
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Account>> oldEngines;

/*****************************************************************
 * Constructor that creates a new BankEngine, the core of the project
 ******************************************************************/
public BankEngine() {
    listAccts = new ArrayList<Account>();
    // actions = new ArrayList<Action>();
    oldEngines = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Account>>();
    oldEngines.add(listAccts);
}
public void undo() {
    if (oldEngines.size() == 0) {

    } else {
        listAccts = oldEngines.get(oldEngines.size()-1); <--- I want this to have the same listAccts pointer.

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do, funcionally?

Answer (score 1):

All the objects in a java process share the same address space i.e. the address space of the running JVM

Comment: But then, how would I fix the problem of the JList that is relying on listAccts not being updated?

Comment: I think use of the term "address space" in the question is misleading, and Dante doesn't really mean that because, as you say, all objects are in the same address space in java. I think he's trying to understand whether he has a copy of the object or a reference to the same object and how he'd do one rather than the other.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to ensure that `listAccts` refers to the same physical object throughout the lifetime of your code. Unless you assign `listAccts` to refer to a different object (in code you haven't shown us), this is a given.

After `oldEngines.add(listAccts)` is executed, `oldEngines` will contain a reference to the same object `listAccts` is referring to. However, `listAccts` is not changed in any way - it still refers to the exact same object!

So - again: unless you reassign `listAccts` in code you haven't shown us - the line

```
listAccts = oldEngines.get(oldEngines.size()-1);
```

looks totally unnecessary to me. In fact, it may be confusing you, if you have added other elements to `oldEngines` in the meantime, as then its last element won't anymore refer to the same object `listAccts` does.

Note also that Java doesn't have *pointers*, only *references*. All non-primitive (object) variables are actually *references*, not by-value copies of an object. And the JVM can actually change the physical memory location of objects under the hood, updating all references to these objects. We have no way to notice this, because there is no way to get the actual physical memory address from a reference (at least within Java - I guess you *could* do it using e.g. JNI). A reference is a higher level of abstraction than a pointer - it is not a memory address. This is why terms like *address space* are meaningless in Java.

#### Update

> what I'm trying to do is make it so that the last oldEngine is now replacing what is the current listAccts.

If you mean to *change the `listAccts` reference* to point to the last element in `oldEngine`, you are already doing that. If you mean to *copy the contents* of the last element in `oldEngine` into the current `listAccts` object (overwriting its current contents), try

```
listAccts.clear();
listAccts.addAll(oldEngines.get(oldEngines.size()-1));
```

Comment: Well, what I'm trying to do is make it so that the last oldEngine is now replacing what is the current listAccts.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want `listAccts` to essentially be the same object  as it was before, i.e. you don't want to create a new list, then what you need to do is:

```
listAccts.addAll(oldEngines.get(oldEngines.size() - 1));
```

i.e., manipulate your existing list rather than creating a new object.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I was passing along the same old listAccts to the array list, without saying "new". Even when I did say "new" i was passing along the accounts inside of listAccts, so the arraylist would be new, but the accounts inside of the new array list would be the ones I wanted to have backups of. What I had to do was create a new object from a deep copy using this method.

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip76.html?page=2

Thanks everyone who offered help.